# Category Theory and Cardinality

Tags: homological-algebra, cardinals

This is a very basic question from Rotman's Homological Algebra text. I think the issue is that I don't know how to rigorously talk about cardinality.

### Problem

If $\mathcal A$ is a *small* category (meaning $\text{obj}(\mathcal A)$ has a cardinal number) and $F, G : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ are functors of the same variance, prove that $\text{Nat}(F,G)$ is a set (i.e. not a proper class).

### Attempted Proof

For each $\tau \in \text{Nat}(F,G)$, there are $K := \text{card(obj}(\mathcal A))$ slots to fill for morphisms $\tau_A$, and for each such morphism there's $L := \text{card(Hom}(FA, GA))$ choices. So  this set has cardinality $K * L$. $\square$

Comment: You have the right idea. The set $\operatorname{Nat}(F,G)$ can be identified with a subset of $\prod_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \operatorname{Hom}(FA, GA)$, specifically the subset satisfying naturality. Note that we can always take arbitrary cartesian products of a set of sets like this to get a new set.

Comment: Let $\tau$ be one of the natural transformations. Can't we construct a distinct $\tau'$ by just changing one $\tau_A$ with another one that satisfies naturality? If so, the cartesian product you presented doesn't account for these repeats. It doesn't seem like an identification to me.

Comment: Actually, I think it's each element of Nat$(F,G)$ that could be identified with that cartesian product.

Comment: An element $\eta$ of that Cartesian product is a choice, for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, of a morphism $\eta_A\colon FA \to GA$. A natural transformation from $F$ to $G$ is also such a choice, with the restriction that it must be natural.

Comment: @Dennis -- sorry I was about to delete my earlier comments from yesterday but forgot. Thanks for the further explanation, I understand now!